# What is the easiest way to parse an INI File in C?

Tags: c, ini, fileparsing

There are some similar questions about C++, Java and C# so now my question is about C. If I have this config file

```
[BBDD]
user=**
password=***
database=***
IPServidor=*
port=3***

[Device]
dev=8
Temperatura=5=1001
Humedad=7=1002
Link=8=1003
Volt=9=1004

[Device]
dev=10
Temperatura=5=1012
Humedad=7=1013
Link=8=1014
Volt=9=1015
```

what is the best way to read the values of Device. I am a linux user. I used glib but I had some problems because there is the same key (Device) so it returns me as the tutorial says only the values of the last Device array. Also Boost as I know has libraries for C++, libconfig also I think is not used for this kind of config files. Finally [iniparser](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/) has a difficult installation guide for me. Do you think that some solutions like sscanf, fprintf are good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problems are you having with using iniparser?  I just tried it.  I first did `make` in the iniparser directory, and the code was built.  To use the library, I did the following:

`gcc test.c ./libiniparser.a`

This was because I had created the test program in the same directory as the library.  When you include `iniparser.h` in C++, make sure to do the following:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "src/iniparser.h"
}
```

Comment: I did the installation using your guide. I think I misunderstood where I should do the make.

Answer (score 5):

> Finally iniparser has a difficult installation guide for me. Do you think that some solutions like sscanf, fprintf are good?

The iniparser may have a difficult installation, but that's a small tradeoff for code that already works, has already been tested, and handles cases that you haven't thought of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you and I know that iniparser is very powerful. Is there any easier installation guide for iniparser? Maybe with more clearly steps for beginners like me?